# PDF viewer/reader that supports cycling through documents

Tags: pdf, software-rec, image-viewer

In my work I generate lot's of eps/pdf files that contain figures and tables. I want to be able cycle through all eps and pdf files in one directory by just clicking next/using a shortcut in my viewer. It is surprisingly difficult to find a viewer/reader that can do that. pdf readers don't support the previous/next file functionality, and image viewers don't support eps/pdf files.

I appreciate any software recommendations.

Comment: probably a simple solution is to convert the eps to pdf and concatenate all the pdfs into one pdf (eg with pdfunite from poppler-utils).

Comment: How is that a simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a software. But you can always use scripts in combination with [keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html) (e.g. killall evince), to close the current file and then have a script open a new file.

```
grep=$(which grep)
files=( *."pdf" )
count=$(printf '%d\n' "${#files[@]}")
no=0
skip=${1:-0}

for i in "${files[@]}"; do
    ((no++))
    if [ $skip -gt $no ]; then
        continue
    fi

    echo $no of $count - $(($no*100/$count)) '%'
    echo -n "Note for file"'['$i']:'

    evince "$i" # -i 3 opens the third page
    # use a shortcut to kill evince here
    clear

    echo $no of $count - $(($no*100/$count)) '%'
    echo -n "Note for file"'['$i']:'
    read ok

    echo $no > .batchview-status
    [ -n "$ok" ] && echo "$i" >> notes.txt
    [ -n "$ok" ] && echo "$ok" >> notes.txt
done
```