# EPS viewer/reader that supports cycling through documents

Tags: bash

I'm in a very similar situation to this:
[PDF viewer/reader that supports cycling through documents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330090/pdf-viewer-reader-that-supports-cycling-through-documents)

The only answer suggest to create a bash script that opens all files, one after the other after killing the previous with a keyboard shortcut. This seems to by a very nice solution but the bash script doesnt work. Given my very limited experience with bash, could you find the problem here and explain me how to do such a script that actually works? Thanks in advance!

```
grep=$(which grep)
files=( *."pdf" )
count=$(printf '%d\n' "${#files[@]}")
no=0
skip=${1:-0}

for i in "${files[@]}"; do
  ((no++))
  if [ $skip -gt $no ]; then
    continue
  fi

  echo $no of $count - $(($no*100/$count)) '%'
  echo -n "Note for file"'['$i']:'

  evince "$i" # -i 3 opens the third page
  # use a shortcut to kill evince here
  clear

  echo $no of $count - $(($no*100/$count)) '%'
  echo -n "Note for file"'['$i']:'
  read ok

  echo $no > .batchview-status
  [ -n "$ok" ] && echo "$i" >> notes.txt
  [ -n "$ok" ] && echo "$ok" >> notes.txt
done
```

Comment: Without knowing what problems you are having, it is difficult to recommend solutions.  Please post any errors you are getting and/or expand on "doesn't work".  Looking at the script you posted, it will require `bash` and would not run in `sh` and it requires the `evince` document viewer to be installed and available in `$PATH`.

Comment: sorry, the error it gives is:
`open_eps.sh: 2: open_eps.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

where open_eps.sh is the name of the bash script

Comment: oh! it runs on `bash` :) sorry, im really a newbie...